# How close can blender simulations get to reality?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

can blender be used to simulate the real forces that are present in a model and can it be used to optimize model shapes? i have tried looking for examples online but found nothing that is satisfactory. to simplify my question how realistic can blender simulations get to real life?

Comment: Blender physics simulations are mostly approximations, good enough to fool your eyes in a render but not much more. I don't think they are precise or accurate enough for anything else. If you are looking for physical accuracy look else where, if just you wan't something that "looks close enough" than it is probably ok

Comment: AFAIK not very close. I think there is an old modified blender version that uses the SOFA-Framework instead of the blender physics engine and would therefore generate much more accurate physical results. However i am quite sure this doesn't exist for the current blender versions(2.79b/2.80)